# Grid Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph, grid

This being my first post on stackoverflow, so pardon me if i am asking a question which has already been answered. Can someone direct me to a good tutorial to help me solve grid problems where we are to do that problem in 'minimum' number of steps possible. Sometimes BFS does help but is not sufficient for other similar problems.
Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll get better answers if you give more details, making your question more specific.

Comment: This question is off topic for Stack Overflow. You should post your question on the Theoretical Computer Science site: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Dan Definitely not. cstheory is for research-level questions. Until [Practical Algorithms and Data Structures](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5120/practical-algorithms-and-data-structures?referrer=Ui8Wpa9dvCjQPozYLE14uw2) launches, this is on-topic here.

Comment: This question is about what algorithms are available for solving a class of problems. That is exactly what cstheory is about. When he actually has code of his own he needs help with, then it's appropriate for SO. This is the same type of question as the OFF TOPIC examples for that proposal.

Comment: @Dan Please refer to the [SO faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), where it explicitly states "software algorithms".

Comment: Yes, SO is for help implementing algorithms. Most of the code we help people write on SO is the right size to call a simple algorithm for some specific problem. SO is not the right place to ask for a list of algorithms suited to a problem class without any implementation.

Comment: @Dan Solving problems at the level of this questions is very much going to include implementation details. Please just add [algorithm] to your ignored tags if you have a stiff lip about the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Without more info, it's hard to give a good answer. Good algorithms depend on the exact statement of the problem.

If the entire grid is defined, and all edges exist and have the same weight, the minimum is easily defined as walking the "diagonal" between two points. No clever algorithm is needed.

If some edges exists, or edges have variable weights which are positive, I would suggest Dijkstra's algorithm. If some edges are negative, there are variants such as Bellman-Ford.

Anyway, you need to elaborate on the setup so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the complexity and the order of the grid you can use space-filling-curve for example a z-curve, hilbert curve or peano curve.